# Produce Histogram of days - including days with zero counts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to produce a histogram of sale counts per day. Some days have no records against them, but I don't want them missed out of my figure

```
df.Name.groupby([df["Created at"].dt.day]).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

This gives me a quick & easy hist, but I don't know how to force my x range onto it

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Use `df.set_index('Created at').resample('D').size().plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
#if dont want omit NaNs
df.resample('D', on='Created at').size().plot.bar()

#if want omit NaNs
df.resample('D', on='Created at').count().plot.bar()
```

EDIT:

Solution for change format of values in axis x:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

s = df.resample('D', on='Created at').size()

ax = s.plot.bar()
ticklabels = s.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the x labels so they don't show 00:00:00 times after dates?

Comment: All values are `00:00:00` or there are sometimes times?

Comment: I add solution, please check it, because I dont test it.

Comment: It does work - it's only the xlabels are showing 2017-10-06 00:00:00. I'd prefer it to have just the date and no times

Comment: but there is problem you cannot convert `datetimes` to dates before resample, because resample need datetimes :(

Comment: I edit answer, I think now it working nice, because tested.